# How to get PEM format from pfx file

Tags: c#, security, cryptography, x509certificate2

I need to pass private key and public key in a json object. (Apirest POST)

If I use "openssl" I get a "cert" file that when I open it with notepad I find the keys but it doesn't help me copy and paste ... it doesn't work for me, I think it's because of the line breaks.

This is my cert file(openssl):

[image]

That is why I need to obtain the keys publicly and privately programmatically.

```
var privateK = cert.PrivateKey.ToXmlString (true); //ERROR
```

I have the certificate installed on my computer, I also know the key to install it on another computer. My application does not use the certificate path, the user chooses it from the store.

I need this:

[image]

Comment: What error happening?

Comment: I still can't understand what you have and what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Pethical "throws Key not valid for use in specified state"

Comment: @Crypt32 I need to send public and private keys by POST (json).

My digital certificate is installed on the computer and the user must choose one to continue. I need to do it programmatically and not with openssl: with this program I convert the pfx file to crt and then open that file with notepad. If I copy and paste the file from the notepad to the json post it works fine but I have to adjust the lines manually with "/ n". That I need to get .... the string of the keys.

Comment: The error says that private key is not marked as exportable. You cannot send the private key anywhere.

Comment: @Crypt32 I have reinstalled the certificate with the correct parameter. But the string (xml) is not the same as what I need. The one I need is the one on the notepad in the photo. ty